# Code style issues found in the above file(s). Forgot to run Prettier?

Tags: prettier, prettier-eslint

I have this problem when I try to check style with prettier --check

```
Code style issues found in the above file(s). Forgot to run Prettier?
```

Comment: This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

Answer (score 67):

```
 npx prettier --write .
```

This command overwrites the code and makes it beautiful.

Comment: gives me the same output

Comment: why is it so? could you explain?